# Unlock files in Perforce getting error file(s) not opened in that changelist

Tags: perforce

A person changes his laptop and discarding this perforce client and workspace. He had 2 files opened in a changelist but not sure on the changelist number.

I have admin rights and tried to unlock the file but couldn't do it

> p4 -p p4ser:1001 unlock  -f //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm
>
> //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm - file(s) not opened in that changelist

Then i tried to find the change list by searching for opened files by that user

> p4 -p p4ser:1001 opened -u joe | grep GP.xlsm
>
> //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm#5 - edit default change (binary+l) by joe@joe_dt *exclusive*

I have the client name now as **joe_dt** and was able to find the changelist using changes

> p4 -p p4ser:1001 changes //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm
>
> Change 34784592 on 2015/05/28 by joe@joe_dt 'added POR stuf'

Now if i try to unlock, i get the same error.

> p4 -p p4ser:1001 unlock -c 34521298 -f //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm
>
> //doc/pascal/projmng/GP.xlsm - file(s) not opened in that changelist.

So now i have the client name alone which does not exists as the laptop was replaced. Don't know in which changelist this file is opened by the user joe.
Unlock -x also didn't help.

Am new to Perforce, can you guys help me how to unlock this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, do this; it'll save you from having to keep typing "-p p4ser:1001".  :)

```
p4 set P4PORT=p4ser:1001
```

The file's not "locked", it's "opened exclusively" -- these are two distinct states, and "unlock" only deals with the "locked" state.

A file can be "opened" but not "locked", and "unlock" takes a file from "opened+locked" to just "opened".  Multiple people may have a file "opened" at the same time, even if one has it "locked", but nobody else can "submit" while somebody else has a lock.

A file with the "+l" filetype, though, is always opened exclusively, regardless of whether it's "locked" -- only one person can even have it open at a time.  To release this the user who has the file open needs to either "submit" or "revert" it -- they can't release the lock while also keeping the file open as you can with a normal "lock".  For an admin to release the file without deleting the client, they need to actually force a "revert" rather than a simple "unlock".

But since joe has discarded this client workspace, the simplest thing is to just delete it:

```
p4 client -d -f joe_dt
```

That should cause any files previously opened on that client to be abandoned, whether they were locked, exclusive, both, or neither.

Comment: Thanks, let me try this. The old client was discarded so let me try to delete it. I would set the port but since there are too many server with various ports i didn't set this up.